# apache rewrite: how do I check for empty or not present query parameter?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

might be best explained with an example:

```
- If I enter either URLs in my brower :
  - www.myhost.com/my-page.html?year=
  - www.myhost.com/my-page.html

- I then want to get redirected to  www.my-2nd-host.com/current-year/my-page.html
```

Any ideas how it's done? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING) !(^|&)year=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^/?my-page\.html$ https://www.my-2nd-host.com/current-year/my-page.html [R=302,L]
```

The regex `(^|&)year=[^&]+` checks for the presence of the `year` URL parameter with a non-empty value. The `!` prefix then *negates* the expression so it is successful when that URL param is either empty or not present at all.